# Точки после подпунктов

Tags: пунктуация

***Всегда*** ли нужно ставить точки в конце подпунктов не при упоминании о них, а непосредственно перед текстом, к ним относящимся, например, после 1.1, 2.4.1, 1.5.7 и др.?

Comment: Непонятно. С подпунктами поступаем так же, как с пунктами, после которых идёт текст.

Comment: То есть **обязательно** надо ставить точку?

Comment: А эти пункты с подпунктами - внутри текста? Или они начинают предложение? абзац?

Comment: Ну как сказать... К примеру, кто-то с кем-то заключил договор, как говорится, о нижеследующем, двоеточие, и дальше пункты с подпунктами идут.

Answer (score 3):

> Разделы должны иметь порядковые номера в пределах всего документа и
>   обозначаться арабскими цифрами с точкой. Номер подраздела состоит из
>   номера раздела и подраздела, разделенных точкой, например 2.3. (третий
>   подраздел второго раздела).
>
> Пункты нумеруются в пределах каждого подраздела. Номер пункта состоит
>   из номера раздела, подраздела и пункта, разделенных точками, например
>   1.1.2. (второй пункт первого подраздела первого раздела). Каждый пункт начинается с абзаца.

ВСЕГДА!

**[3.1. Правила оформления разделов, подразделов, пунктов](http://abc.vvsu.ru/Books/d_infosysec/page0010.asp)**

Comment: Действительно, если Вы утверждаете, что и при упоминании надо ставить, как тут ошибочно поставили, то я не согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Если ссылка на подпункт находится в середине предложения, то точка в конце номера подпункта НЕ СТАВИТСЯ НИКОГДА.

Например:  *Номер подраздела состоит из номера раздела и подраздела, разделенных точкой, например **2.3** (третий подраздел второго раздела).*

В методичке, размещенной в Интернете, ошибки, противоречащие ее же формулировкам. Точка, как следует из данного текста, РАЗДЕЛЯЕТ номера, а не номер и текст.

Comment: То, что в середине при указании не ставится, я и так понимаю. Просто не заметил, что в цитатах Галины неправильно предлагают. Меня интересует, надо ли разделять с текстом вначале (когда идёт пункт, а дальше текст, относящийся к нему).

Comment: Если речь идет о заглавии, точка разделяет номер и название подпункта. Напр.: 1.2. Правила рубрикации. Если номер и название в середине предложения, оформляется так: ... (см. п. 1.2 "Правила рубрикации").

Comment: Если после номера подпункта начинается текст без названия, точка ставится.